# How can I get the fields from another mongodb collection and add those field values as an array in the current collection?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

For example, I have two collections with the following data:

Collection 1:

```
{
code: 1,
name: "data1"
},
{
code: 2,
name: "data2"
}
```

Collection 2:

```
{
code: 1,
type: "type1"
},
{
code: 1,
type: "type2"
},
{
code: 2,
type: "type2"
},
```

I want the output of the aggregation to be as follows:

```
{
code:1,
name: "data1",
types: ["type1","type2"]
},
{
code:2,
name:"data2",
types:["type2"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to to join collection, pass code as `localField` and `foreignField`
- [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) to get only `type` field from collection2

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "col2",
      "localField": "code",
      "foreignField": "code",
      "as": "type"
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { type: "$type.type" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rpsRCnIg-vh)